# Karma-Runner output in Jenkins log

Tags: jenkins, karma-runner

I run Javascript tests with Karma-Runner on Jenkins in a project I am working on. This is all going really well (headless Chrome and all) but the output in the Jenkins console log is clogged up by the karma module building output.

It looks something like this:

> $ karma start ./karma.conf.js
>
> 0% compiling 10% building modules 0/1 modules 1 active multi /usr/src/app/src/polyfills.ts                                     10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active 10% building modules 1/2 modules 1 active ...src/index.js!/usr/src/app/src/test.ts
>
> ...

There doesn't seem to be an option to hide that output anywhere. I tried a lot of different reporters but this apparently happens way before reporters take action. Running this with angular and applying --progress=false has also not changed the behavior. Has anyone ever had an issue with this and found a way to hide those unnecessary texts from their Jenkins command line output? Any help would be greatly appreciated.